# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown", "-s") not working in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, system-shutdown

i am writing  visual basic application in visual studio 2012 to turn of the computer.
i have used syntaxes like

```
 1. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown", "-s") 
 2.System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown", "/s")

 3. Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /f /t 01")
 4. Shell("shutdown -s -t 00")
```

but all instead of shutting down reruns the same application again and computer dont shutdown only.what might be the solution for it so that it will work

thanks in anticipation

Comment: What do you mean by *reruns*? Is it run once again only once? Maybe your exe file is called `shutdown` also?

Comment: @KonradKokosa...yes....you are right..i renamed the file..
and i got it working...thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your application executable file from `shutdown` to something else because in case of the name `shutdown`, it hides system wide `shutdown` command.